# $_POST[] doesn't work in php 5.4.33

Tags: java, php, android, post

I have an android app that gets data from database through php.. My php code worked fine in php 5.5 but when I changed to php 5.4.33 my code doesn't work.. Here is my code :

```
$username = $_POST['UN'];
$password = $_POST['PW'];

echo $username;
echo $password;
```

Comment: Something else is wrong then. Nothing has changed regarding `$_POST` in a very long time

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` prints what?

Comment: There are two possibilities here: 1) there is some other part of the code which is causing the problem; make sure you are testing a minimal example like you have here, not just assuming it won't work. 2) there is some other difference between the environments that you are not taking into account; for instance, is there a firewall or proxy which could be interfering between the app and the PHP? Or perhaps PHP is misconfigured on the "new" server.

Comment: It prints array(0) {}

Comment: IMSoP, Im connecting to new server but how can I fix that ?